# How to config VIM to support multiple asm syntax

Tags: vim

I have mainly two types of assembly files types:

1. GNU AS
2. ARM ASM

And the filenames look like: `example.s` and `example.asm`

I download both syntax plugins for these two file types, and I add them into:

```
$HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-gas/
$HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-armasm/
```

I set:

```
let asmsyntax='armasm'
let filetype_inc='armasm'
```

then I can see the highlight for ARM asm file.

I changed them to:

```
let asmsyntax='gas'
let filetype_inc='gas'
```

Then I can see the highlight for GNU AS file.

My question is how can I add both of them into one `.vimrc` file? I tried `+=` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you follow the rest of the installation instructions for each package? vim-armasm: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=888 vm-gas: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2863

Comment: yes, I followed them all

Comment: You might want to put those steps into your question - from reading your question and the installation instructions it looked like you didn't follow the vim-gas instructions at all (one instruction: set the filetype), and didn't do the `:call SetSyn("armasm")` step for vim-armasm.

Comment: @verdammelt, I have no problem to use `gas` and `armasm` highlight individually, my question is how to add both configuration into `.vimrc` and if I open `*.s`, it will use `gas`, and I open `*.asm`, it will use `armasm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, I put:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.s   let asmsyntax='gas'|let filetype_inc='gas'
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.asm let asmsyntax='armasm'|let filetype_inc='armasm'
```

in my `$HOME/.vimrc` and now it can automatic detect different assembly file type, namely, `*.s` and `*.asm`, then apply different or dedicate highlight scheme to different files.